# How often have goalkeepers gotten assists in the Premier League?

Tags: football

In last week's Premier League action, Ederson, the goalkeeper for Manchester City, actually got an assist for İlkay Gündoğan's goal against Spurs at the Etihad. That made me wonder how rare such an occurrence really is. I know only a handful of goalies have scored goals, but how many actually got assists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you asked for the occurrence in the Premier League, so far 55 goalkeepers got assists since the league began in 1992/93, with some notable names like Paul Robinson, Pepe Reina, Tim Howard, Petr Cech, Alisson and of course, Ederson. I would say that this doesn't happen often but still it's a cool thing in football.

For example, Reina got four assists during his career in Premier League with Liverpool, with details:

| Opponent | Liverpool's Side | Date | Result | Player Reina gave assist to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fulham | Home | 11/10/2007 | 2-0 | Fernando Torres |
| Man. United | Away | 3/14/2009 | 1-4 | Andrea Dossena |
| Aston Villa | Home | 3/22/2009 | 5-0 | Albert Riera |
| Sunderland | Home | 3/28/2010 | 3-0 | Fernando Torres |

You can find full stats of goalkeeper assists in Premier League on [this](https://www.premierleague.com/stats/top/players/goal_assist?se=54) page.